# Jhipster application deployed using Heroku but after connecting to github build is not triggered

Tags: github, heroku, logging, deployment, jhipster

I followed the following steps.

- Created a Jhipster application.
- Executed `jhipster heroku`
- My application was deployed properly on Heroku
- In Heroku I enabled Github connection and selected automatic deploys.
- However now when I push a change to github, heroku build gets triggered but it does not really builds the project jar to be deployed, so I get the following error in the log.

`2020-08-13T11:33:05.593207+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them. 2020-08-13T11:33:05.594542+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/*.jar`

Here is the log

```
-----> Installing JDK 11... done
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 59.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v11
       https://app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: I have never connected github to heroku, but can you check what command is executed to create the jar? I guess you are using gradle? Which version of jhipster are you using?

Comment: I use the following command to build the jar locally.

`./gradlew -Pprod bootJar -x test  `

Since the github push does not trigger the build so  I use the following to deploy the build directly to heroku from my command line

`heroku deploy:jar build/libs/*jar `

Using the Jhipster 6.10.0 version

Comment: I am a little confused. Does the github push trigger anything on your connected heroku application and it can't find/build the jar file or does it not trigger anything?

Comment: When I push a change in github, the build gets triggered in Heroku, above is the build log I shared, but looks like it just tries to find the jar to deploy, but it does not find it. I am assuming it should build the jar first and then first deploy

Comment: I am not familiar how heroku and github are supposed to work. Did you select to deploy via git or jar when executing jhipster heroku?